# Enable virtualization in Lenovo y650

Tags: virtualization, bios

Has anyone successfully enabled Virtualization in the latest Phoenix BIOS (v2.8) for Lenovo Y650? I have tried the solution mentioned in [this](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-and-Z-series/Y650-virtualization-Intel-VT-SOLVED/td-p/180339) thread but it doesnt seem to work. The Intel Processor Utility confirmed that I have Virtualization.

Comment: What exactly does make you think 'it doesnt seem to work'?

Comment: @gertvdijk I dont see any option in the BIOS to enable virtualization plus when I run a virtual machine using Virtual Box it says VT-X not enabled.